# Put horizontal lines above and below tabbing and prohibit page breaks between the lines and the tabbing contents

Tags: page-breaking, rules, line, tabbing

I wish to put a horizontal line above tabbing and another one below it in such a way that there are no page breaks between the tabbing contents and the two lines.
Here is what I tried so far:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\newenvironment{ruletabbing}{%
\begingroup\setlength{\topsep}{0pt}\setlength{\partopsep}{0pt}\raggedright\hrule\nopagebreak\tabbing\nopagebreak%
}{%
\nopagebreak\endtabbing\nopagebreak\vspace{-.05\baselineskip}\nopagebreak\hrule\par\vspace{.07\baselineskip}\endgroup%
}
\begin{document}
\strut
\vspace{46.8\baselineskip}\\
A page break after this text would be ok.\\[.1\baselineskip]
\begin{ruletabbing}
  A page break after this text in tabbing, but not before it, would be ok.\\
  A page break before this text in tabbing, but not after it, would be ok.
\end{ruletabbing}
\noindent A page break before this text would be ok.
\end{document}
```

However, the `\nopagebreak`s seem to have no effect; this example blatantly fails:

[image: output]

Above, there is a page break right after the first rule, which is NOT what we want. If it doesn't fail for you, adapt 46.8 above slightly. The same problem we have for the second line, by means of changing 46.8 to a particular smaller value.

How to forbid page breaks between the two horizontal lines and the tabbing contents? The tabbing conents should be allowed to have page breaks inside by all means. Ideally, the new tabbing environment should also work inside lists (itemize, enumerate, description), though it's not a must.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User-almost-half-a-million probably isn't reading, but preventing the page breaks around a tabbing environment is a fairly simple matter of telling the tabbing *not* to promote breaks in those places, as it normally does. Those settings would go in the same place as one puts the settings that prevent the extra white space.

```
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{ruletabbing}{%
  \setlength{\topsep}{0pt}\setlength{\partopsep}{0pt}%
  \raggedright
  \@nobreaktrue % no favorable break at start
  \@endparpenalty=10000 % no favorable break at end
  \hrule\nopagebreak\tabbing
}{%
  \endtabbing
  \vspace{-.05\baselineskip}\hrule\vspace{.07\baselineskip}%
}
\makeatother
```

I have copied the spacing, but note that `\hrule` is problematic because it does not play nice with normal interline spacing rules.

Comment: Oops, yes!  Hi! For the `\hrule` I was thinking of how the positioning is sensitive to the presence or absence of descenders on letters. My preference would be a rule inside `\hbox`, or some adjustment of/from the `\prevdepth` to get something akin to how `\baselineskip` is applied between lines.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **tcolorbox**

```
\documentclass{book} 
\usepackage{tcolorbox} 

\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[boxrule=0mm,toprule=1mm,bottomrule=1mm,colback=white,arc=0mm]
content
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

or

```
\documentclass{book} 
\usepackage{tcolorbox} 
\newenvironment{ruletabbing}{%
\begingroup\setlength{\topsep}{0pt}\setlength{\partopsep}{0pt}\raggedright\hrule\nopagebreak\tabbing\nopagebreak%
}{%
\nopagebreak\endtabbing\nopagebreak\vspace{-.05\baselineskip}\nopagebreak\hrule\par\vspace{.07\baselineskip}\endgroup%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[boxrule=0mm,toprule=0mm,bottomrule=0mm,colback=white,arc=0mm]
\begin{ruletabbing}
  A page break after this text in tabbing, but not before it, would be ok.\\
  A page break before this text in tabbing, but not after it, would be ok.
\end{ruletabbing}
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @user0 sandu edited his answer. Is his answer ok now?